# Missing handle view in slider Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Hi in my jquery mobile app, i am missing the handler ,i made up the slider with **div**  i want it to look as below

[image]

first of all i am unable to see the handle , and also i wanna see a value in the handle i am doing it as below

HTML :

```
 <div id="slider">

        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
        <div id="blue"></div>

    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#slider").slider({

});
```

**Css**

```
#slider {
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
}
#red {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
#green {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
#blue {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for a continuous slider with multi-colored background, or for a 3 state flip switch (http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/m48dT/114/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the jQM slider widget and just add the 3 color segments in the slider track you can do it like this:

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3Gc2z/)**

Use standard markup for the slider, I have put it in a container for convenience:

```
<div id="sliderContainer" >
    <label for="theSlider">A Slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="theSlider" id="theSlider" min="0" max="200" value="60" />
</div>
```

In code, insert the color divs into the jQM slider track that is created when the slider is enhanced:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    var colorback = '<div class="sliderBackColor red">Low</div><div class="sliderBackColor green">Medium</div><div class="sliderBackColor blue">High</div>';

    $("#sliderContainer .ui-slider-track").prepend(colorback);

});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.sliderBackColor{
    height: 100%;
    width: 33.33%;    
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 0;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.3125em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3125em;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.3125em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3125em;
}
```

NOTE: if you want the track taller like in your image, you can adjust the CSS to taste.

> Taller track **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3Gc2z/1/)**

Comment: @ezanker..Thanks a lot..is it possible to make the handler fixed. what i want is i want the set a value and user should not be able to move the handler?

Comment: Yes, set slider to disabled and adjust disabled CSS to full opacity: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3Gc2z/2/